# Debugging Fatal Error - alloc: invalid block: 0000000001F00AEF0: 0 0

Tags: memory, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a GUI written in R that utilizes Tcl/TK package as well a C .dll that also uses Tcl library. I have done some research on this issue, and it seems to be memory related. I am an inexperienced programmer, so I am not sure where I should be looking for this memory issue. Each call of `malloc()` has a matching `free()`, and same with the analogous `Tcl_Alloc()` and `Tcl_Free()`. This error is very hard to reproduce as well, thus I am afraid I cannot provide a reproducible example as it is seemingly random in nature. One pattern is however that it seems to only happen upon closure of the program, though this is very inconsistent.

By making this post, I am hoping to gain a logical process that one should take in an attempt to debug this problem in a general context under Tcl/Tk - C - R applications. I am not looking for a solution specific to my code, but rather what an individual should think about when encountering this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message comes from the function `Ptr2Block()` in `tclThreadAlloc.c` (or there's something else about which produces the same error message; possible but unlikely) which is Tcl's thread-specific memory allocator (which is used widely inside Tcl to reduce the number of times global locks are hit). Specifically, it's this bit:

```c
if (blockPtr->magicNum1 != MAGIC || blockPtr->magicNum2 != MAGIC) {
    Tcl_Panic("alloc: invalid block: %p: %x %x",
            blockPtr, blockPtr->magicNum1, blockPtr->magicNum2);
}
```

The problem? Those zeroes should be `MAGIC` (which is equal to `0xEF`). This indicates that *something* has overwritten the memory block's metadata — which also should include the size of the block, but that is now likely hot garbage — and program memory integrity can no longer be trusted. Alas, at this point we're now dealing with a program in a broken state where the breakage happened some time previously; the place where the panic happened is merely where *detection* of the bug happened, not the actual *location* of the bug.

Debugging further is usually done by building a version of *everything* with fancy memory allocators turned off (in Tcl's code, this is done by defining the `PURIFY` symbol when building) and then running the resulting code — which hopefully still has the bug — with a tool like `electricfence` or `purify` (hence the special symbol name) to see what sort of out-of-bounds errors are found; they're very good at hunting down this sort of issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to start by having a closer look to the `sizeof()` values provided to your `Tcl_Alloc()` calls in this C .dll.

I'm writing myself a Tcl binding for a C library and I faced recently exactly the same problem and therefore I'm assuming you may have the same error than me in your code.

Here below a minimal example that reproduces the problem:

```
    #include <tcl.h>
    #include <stdlib.h> // malloc
    
    static unsigned int dataCtr;
    
    struct tDataWrapper {
        const char *str; // Tcl_GetCommandName(interp, cmd)
        unsigned int n; // dataCtr value
        void *data; // pointer to wrapped object
    };
    
    static void wrapDelCmd(ClientData clientData)
    {
        struct tDataWrapper *wrap = (struct tDataWrapper *) clientData;
        if (wrap != NULL) {

            /* with false sizeof value provided while creating the wrapper
             * (see above), this data pointer would overwrite the
             * overhead section of the allocated tcl memory block
             * from what I understood and this is what can be causing
             * the panic with message like following one when the
             * memory is freed with ckfree (here after calling unload)
             * alloc: invalid block: 0000018F2624E760: 0 0 */
            printf("DEBUG: @%s(%s) &wrap->data @%p\n", 
                __func__, wrap->str, &wrap->data);
        
            if (wrap->data != NULL) {
                // call your wrapped API to deinstantiate the object
            }
            ckfree(wrap);
        }
    }
    
    static int wrapCmd(ClientData clientData, Tcl_Interp *interp,
            int objc, Tcl_Obj *const objv[])
    {
        struct tDataWrapper *wrap = (struct tDataWrapper *) clientData;
        if (wrap == NULL)
            return TCL_ERROR;
    
        else if (wrap->data != NULL) {
            // call your wrapped API to do something with instantiated object
            return TCL_OK;
    
        } else {
            Tcl_Obj *obj = Tcl_ObjPrintf("wrap: {str=\"%s\", n=%u, data=%llx}",
                    wrap->str, wrap->n, (unsigned long long) wrap->data);
            if (obj != NULL) {
                Tcl_SetObjResult(interp, obj);
                return TCL_OK;
            } else
                return TCL_ERROR;
        }
    }
    
    static int newCmd(ClientData clientData, Tcl_Interp *interp,
            int objc, Tcl_Obj *const objv[])
    {
        struct tDataWrapper *wrap;
        Tcl_Obj *obj;
        Tcl_Command cmd;
    
        // 3) this is correct
        // if ((wrap = attemptckalloc(sizeof(struct tDataWrapper))) == NULL)
        // 2) still incorrect but GCC gives more warning regarding the inconsistent pointer handling
        // if ((wrap = malloc(sizeof(struct tDataWrapper *))) == NULL)
        // 1) this is incorrect
        if ((wrap = attemptckalloc(sizeof(struct tDataWrapper *))) == NULL)
            Tcl_Panic("%s:%u: attemptckalloc failed\n", __func__, __LINE__);
    
        else if ((obj = Tcl_ObjPrintf("data%u", dataCtr+1)) == NULL)
            Tcl_Panic("%s:%u: Tcl_ObjPrintf failed\n", __func__, __LINE__);
    
        else if ((cmd = Tcl_CreateObjCommand(interp, Tcl_GetString(obj),
                    wrapCmd, (ClientData) wrap, wrapDelCmd)) == NULL)
            Tcl_Panic("%s:%u: Tcl_CreateObjCommand failed\n", __func__, __LINE__);
    
        else {
            wrap->str = Tcl_GetCommandName(interp, cmd);
            wrap->n = dataCtr;
            wrap->data = NULL; // call your wrapped API to instantiate an object
    
            dataCtr++;
            Tcl_SetObjResult(interp, obj);
        }
    
        return TCL_OK;
    }
    
    int Allocinvalidblock_Init(Tcl_Interp *interp)
    {
        dataCtr = 0;
    
        return (Tcl_CreateObjCommand(interp, "new",
            newCmd, (ClientData) NULL, NULL)
            == NULL) ? TCL_ERROR : TCL_OK;
    }
    
    int Allocinvalidblock_Unload(Tcl_Interp *interp, int flags)
    {
        Tcl_Namespace *ns = Tcl_GetGlobalNamespace(interp);
        Tcl_Obj *obj;
        Tcl_Command cmd;
        unsigned int i;
        for(i=0; i<dataCtr; i++) {
            if ((obj = Tcl_ObjPrintf("data%u", i+1)) != NULL) {
                if ((cmd = Tcl_FindCommand(interp,
                    Tcl_GetString(obj), ns, TCL_GLOBAL_ONLY)) != NULL)
                    Tcl_DeleteCommandFromToken(interp, cmd);
                Tcl_DecrRefCount(obj);
            }
        }
    
        return TCL_OK;
    }
```

Once built (for example with Code::Blocks as shared library project linking against C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libtcl.dll.a), the error can be triggered when more than a data object is created and the library immediately unloaded:

```
    load bin/Release/libAllocInvalidBlock.dll
    new
    new
    unload bin/Release/libAllocInvalidBlock.dll
```

If used otherwise the crash may even be not triggered... Anyway, such an error in the C code is not particularly obvious to identify (although easy to fix) because the compilation is running without any warning (although `-Wall` compiler flag is set).